# How can I configure puma when running Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, puma

I'd like to adjust the puma configuration when running Capybara tests. Changing settings in .env, .env.test (I use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)), or config/puma.rb has no effect.

Where can I change the configuration?

Rails 5.1, poltergeist 1.15.0, capybara 2.14.0, puma 2.8.2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally with Capybara you configure the server in a register_server block.  The :puma server definition Capybara provides is

```
Capybara.register_server :puma do |app, port, host|
  require 'rack/handler/puma'
  Rack::Handler::Puma.run(app, Host: host, Port: port, Threads: "0:4")
end
```

If you're using Rails 5.1 system testing it has added a layer of abstraction on top of that with server configuration being done in
ActionDispatch::SystemTesting::Server#register which is defined as

```
def register
  Capybara.register_server :rails_puma do |app, port, host|
    Rack::Handler::Puma.run(app, Port: port, Threads: "0:1")
  end
end
```

Either way you should be able to either overwrite one of the current server registrations

```
Capybara.register_server :rails_puma do |app, port,host|
  Rack::Handler::Puma.run(app, ...custom settings...)
end
```

or configure your own

```
Capybara.register_server :my_custom_puma do |app, port, host|
  Rack::Handler::Puma.run(app, ...custom settings...)
end

Capybara.server = :my_custom_puma
```

Comment: thanks! I'm not totally clear on what you mean by "overwrite one of the current server registrations" -- could you show some example code and say which file it goes in? Do you mean to overwrite `ActionDispatch::SystemTesting::Server.register`?

Comment: @JohnBachir Just put the code from above that reregisters :rails_puma in whatever file you configure your tests in - it should overwrite the registration Rails made

Comment: For the record, the only way I could get this to work was by redefining my own server (`:my_custom_puma`) and putting it at the bottom of application_system_test_case.rb. Any other location in application_system_test_case.rb or test_helper.rb didn't work, and trying to redefine `:rails_puma` didn't work.

Comment: @JohnBachir ok - what exactly were you changing in the puma config?

Comment: Here's my code at the bottom of application_system_test_case.rb https://gist.github.com/jjb/a0555b3cc760f9b0f097fa0fbfe1d87f

Comment: Try `Rack::Handler::Puma.run(app, Port: port, Threads: "0:1", Silent: true)` to boot without the boot message.

Comment: @Epigene If all you want to do is silence Puma, and you're using a current version of Capybara, you should be able to just do `Capybara.server = :puma, { Silent: true }`  or set `ActionDispatch::SystemTesting::Server.silence_puma = true` if using Rails system tests.

Answer (score 9):

In `ApplicationSystemTestCase`, you can configure by passing `options` to the default `:puma` server used by Rails in `setup`.

AFAIK, this will work for any options, but I've only used

- `Silent: true` to silence the puma startup output
- `Thread: '1:1'` to configure the puma process to only use one thread

Here's how I've setup up rails systems tests to run inside docker containers:

```
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400], options: { url: "http://selenium:4444/wd/hub" }

  def setup
    Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0' # bind to all interfaces
    Capybara.server = :puma, { Silent: true, Threads: '1:1' }
    host! "http://#{IPSocket.getaddress(Socket.gethostname)}"
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the only comment that successfully resolved the puma hanging issue.  Thank you @erroric

Comment: I am trying to test through SSL, and this solutions works to setup Puma with SSL listener, but the test are trying to connect to the host without SSL, and they dont run. Do you know any way to solve this?