# How can I simulate two fast clicks on a submit button in Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I have a bug in my app which occurs if a user clicks the submit button of a form very quickly twice in a row. I can reliably reproduce this on production and in my development environment.

Is it possible for me to reproduce this with Capybara/poltergeist/phantomjs?

`find("#my-button").double_click`, `find("#my-button").click.click`, `execute_script("$('#register-button').click().click();")`, and other variations with `execute_script` do not work.

Everything I tried only caused my server-side code to be invoked once, even though `console.log` logging showed that `click` was indeed invoked twice. So I suspect there's something fundamentally missing from the capabilities of capybara and poltergeist simulate this behavior.

Is there a way to somehow invoke phantomJS at a lower level and achieve this?

I did try [increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926898) the concurrency of my web server, it didn't help.

---

- capybara 2.14.0
- rails 5.1.0
- poltergeist 1.15.0
- phantomjs 2.1.1

Answer (score 2):

As you guessed - `double_click` is not the same as click twice.  To have two clicks you can do

```
find("#my-button").click.click
```

Or, depending on your bug you may need to sleep a little between those two clicks

```
find("#my-button").tap do |b|
  b.click
  sleep 0.1
  b.click
end
```

Comment: When I try `click.click`, I'm told that the element I want to click on isn't there, and then the screenshot looks like I only clicked once. My guess: capybara is waiting for the submission to finish and the DOM to reload before doing the second click? If so then I think I need to do a "lower level" click which doesn't wait for things to finish.

Comment: @JohnBachir Capybara doesn't wait for things to finish, but it is possible (not guaranteed) for the driver (selenium, poltergeist, etc) to be waiting if it can detect some kind of page load is happening.  The only "lower level" click would be to use execute_script to create and fire click events manually.

Comment: I've tried `execute_script("$('#register-button').click().click();")` and other variations to no avail, I can't reproduce the bug in the capybara environment.

Comment: @JohnBachir   Hmmm.. you may need to introduce a delay in the request to simulate a user over the network, you should be able to delay requests a bit with something like puffing-billy

Comment: Moving to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145496/how-can-i-simulate-double-clicking-a-submit-button-twice-in-capybara

Comment: Hey Thomas -- I think your solution doesn't have the effect I'm looking for. If you agree, could you remove your answer so the question gets more attention? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnBachir  Given the requirements you've posted, my answer is the only possible solution.  If it doesn't work then what you want isn't possible with Capybara using Poltergeist.  You might want to update your question (or ask a new one) that specifically says you need to trigger two submits of a normal html form simultaneously

Comment: Could you remove your answer?

Comment: @JohnBachir I'm unclear why you want me to remove my answer - it details what was tried for anyone else coming along that would propose the same thing, and since you haven't accepted it your question is not marked as answered.  Your issue isn't that no one is reading your question, it's that the only possible answers have already been given and they don't solve your issue - which leads to the conclusion that what you want isn't possible with Capybara and Poltergeist

Comment: I guess I figured that I'd changed my question enough so that your answer is interesting information but orthogonal.

I was hoping that maybe there was a hacky way to invoke another type of behavior on PhantomJS itself.

Comment: I mean, don't get me wrong, I imagine that you are among the top experts on this topic, and it seems you are implying it's not possible! :) but you never said that so I wasn't sure if you felt there might be other things to explore that you weren't aware of.

Comment: @JohnBachir It's really hard to say something is completely impossible, but I'm pretty convinced this is close (with the restriction that it has to be done with Poltergeist/PhantomJS).  You can see from https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/browser.coffee#L288 that poltergeist waits 5ms to detect if a page change is occurring and if it is it waits for it to complete - So the ruby `.click.click` can't do what you want, calling `el.trigger('click').trigger('click')` would get around that Poltergeist check but it's equivalent to the JS method.

Comment: @JohnBachir So if the `execute_script` version can't trigger it (but does trigger the action of one click) then `trigger` isn't going to work either.  Other than those there is no other way to interact with PhantomJS through Poltergeist.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a slightly different approach here: what is the fix to this bug? Would it be easier to test the fix, rather than test that these actions can't be carried out?

For example, if the fix is to use Rails UJS `disable-with` on an `<input type=submit>`, then your test could be something like:

```
# replace `your_path` as required
visit your_path

# important: this stops the submission so the page doesn't change;
# but crucially doesn't stop UJS from doing its thing
execute_script("$('form').submit(function() { event.preventDefault() })")

# replace 'Submit form' and 'Processing...' text as appropriate
click_button('Submit form')
expect(page).to have_button('Processing...', disabled: true)
```

Comment: Gray out a button once user clicks on a Button, and enable back once job was done.

Comment: That would be a test of the JS (the implementation) and would have some value, but wouldn't be ideal. But thanks for sharing!